# Formatting Excel Cell (custom format)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to accomplish the following when formatting an Excel cell:

```
Number less than 10 -> 2 decimal places
Number greater than 10 -> no decimal places
Zero -> two dashes (i.e --)
```

I have the following format that I put into the custom cell format, but it doesn't seem to work for the zero:

```
[<10]$0.00;$#,###
```

Many thanks!

Comment: What about numbers less than zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does what you asked for:

```
[=0]"--";[<10]$0.00;$#,###
```

You want the zero condition first, as it's the most restrictive. All values less than zero will also be formatted per your `"<10"` specification.